# Test file asking for multiple command line arguments, argparse is in other file

Tags: python

I can't figure out why my test file is asking for more arguments. I've implemented argparse in my foo file, but not in the test file.

```
$ python test_foo.py
usage: test_foo.py [-h] inputfile dictionary
test_foo.py: error: too few arguments
```

If I pass in more arguments:

```
$ python test_foo.py inputfile.txt dictionary.txt

[OUTPUT FROM FOO]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_foo.py", line 22, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'input'
```

I also don't know why it outputs the result of foo, since I'm only asking it to import two functions. Here's my code:

```
#test_foo.py
import unittest
from foo import my_function, another_function
class TestFooMethods(unittest.TestCase):
  [everything commented out]
if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

and:

```
#foo.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('inputfile', action="store")
parser.add_argument('dictionary', action="store")

def my_function(inputfile):
  [code]

def another_function(dictionary):
  [code]

my_function(inputfile)
another_function(dictionary)
print(OUTPUT FROM FOO)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `import foo`, the file `foo.py` in running. That's why you're being asked for arguments. You should add `if "__main__" == __name__:` and put all your code in it (except function definitions and imports).

When you run foo.py, its `__name__` will be `"__main__"`. But when you import it, its name will be `"foo"`.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it, and the explanation of what to add above and below the line was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! You may want to read further about the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: That link is an excellent rabbit hole of information, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

following up on Ella Shar' answer, here's a quick demonstartion:

```
# foo.py

def bar(foo):
    return foo

print 'hi'
```

running

```
>>> from foo import bar
```

outputs:

```
>>> hi
```

correct way:

```
# foo.py

def bar(foo):
    return foo

if __name__ == 'main':
    print 'hi'
```

outputs:  will simply prompt you for next command

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciated the clear breakdown, and this fixed it really quickly.